# why rqt_logger_level is used?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could not  understand the functionality of rqt_logger_level

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251298/why-rqt_logger_level-is-used?/) by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2017-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The logger levels are there to filter the amount of output you see. On level 'debug', a node will spit out all kinds of details about its operation. On level 'warning', it will be silent except for messages that point out something is out of the ordinary. [Here](http://wiki.ros.org/Verbosity%20Levels) is wiki about it.

---

Originally posted by [bouke](https://answers.ros.org/users/28943/bouke/) with karma: 61 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2